# Remove and replace characters from string with one command

Tags: bash

I need to remove characters from string and then replace other characters.
This is the initial string:

```
something/filename.txt
```

I need to remove the directory "something" (can be any other name) and replace .txt with .gz
The following 2 commmands work perfect:

```
newfile=${newfile#*/}
newfile=${newfile::-4}.gz
```

So the output will be: **filename.gz**
Is there a way to do it in a single command? Something like:

```
${${$newfile#*/}::-4}.gz
```

With the above command I get: bad substitution error.

Thank you
Lucas

Comment: You get a bad substitution because Parameter Expansions works on parameters (variables), e.g. `${param#*/}` and `${param::-4}`. In `${${newfile#*/}::-4}.gz `, `${newfile#*/}` is NOT a parameter. Use 2 parameter expansions and don't worry about combining them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use `basename`, i.e.

```
name_of_file="something/filename.txt"
newfile=$(basename "${name_of_file%%.*}".gz)
echo "$newfile"
filename.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your question is tagged bash, you can use Bash builtin regex to capture the group you need like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

filepath=something/filename.txt

# Regex group capture basename without dot suffix || exit err if not matching
[[ $filepath =~ .*/(.*)\.[^.]* ]] || exit

# Compose new file name from Regex captured group and new .gz extension
newfilename=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.gz

# debug dump variables
declare -p filepath newfilename
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_file=something/filename.txt
new_file="${new_file#*/}"
new_file="${new_file%.*}.gz"
```

---

> Is there a way to do it in a single command?

```
echo something/filename.txt | sed 's|.*/||;s|\..*$|.gz|'
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `cut` and `sed` can help as below

```
oldfile='somethingelse/filename.txt'
newfile=`echo $oldfile | cut -d "/" -f2 |sed 's!.txt!.gz!g'`
echo $newfile
```

This displays `filename.gz`

**EDIT**
In case there are subdirectories and you want only file name

```
oldfile='somethingelse/other/filename.txt'
newfile=`echo $oldfile | rev| cut -d "/" -f1 |rev |sed 's!.txt!.gz!g'`
echo $newfile
```

The cut command gets the last field delimited by "/" .

Happy to be corrected and learn.